Spring Boot 3.3.5 webflux dependency causing threads to block with state of TIMED_WAITING
Kotlin: 2.0.21, Spring Boot: 3.3.5, Spring Cloud: 2023.0.3.
My Project is a REST API using Hikari for connection pooling. When I run many concurrent requests against my app, I can see that some connections never return to HikariPool
HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=3, idle=7, waiting=0)

I got a thread dump and can see many threads are in TIMED_WAITING state.
http-nio-7900-exec-18 (waiting on condition)

http-nio-7900-exec-18" prio=0 tid=0x0 nid=0x0 waiting on condition
     java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
 on kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine@70dc10b
    at java.base@22.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

All the waiting on condition threads are running
Kotlin runBloking code in which I'm using org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient. As an example,
<code-removed-for-brevity>

val result: Map<String, Any> = runBlocking {
  getFileDetails("user1", fileId)
}

private fun createWebClient(username: String, logging: Boolean = true): WebClient {
    return WebClient.builder()
        .uriBuilderFactory(factory)
        .clientConnector(if (logging) loggingConnector else nonLoggingConnector)
        .filters { exchangeFilterFunctions -> filters.forEach { exchangeFilterFunctions.add(it) } }
        .codecs { it.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(MAX_MEMORY_SIZE) }
        .build()
}

private suspend fun getFileDetails(
    username: String,
    fileId: Long,
): Map<String, Any> {
    return createWebClient(username)
      .get()
      .uri { uriBuilder ->
        uriBuilder
            .path("/files/$fileId")
            .build()
      }
      .retrieve()
      .awaitBody()
}

Note that:

Spring Boot 3.3.5 brings in spring-webflux version 6.1.14.
Same code works in 3.3.4 which brings in spring-webflux version 6.1.13.
I use Spring mvc in controller and not reactive controller.

If I override spring-webflux in my pom back to 6.1.13 everything works just fine. There are no threads in TIMED_WAITING and HiKari pool will show active connection of 0 at the end of my concurrent test.
Is this a bug related to spring-webflux version 6.1.14?

You would probably have better luck opening this as an issue on the spring forum. It does look like a bug.
